# How to get MOQ of child that inside the bundle?

Tags: magento2, products, quantity

How to get MOQ (default quantity) of child product option that inside the bundle?
Bundle itself doesn't contains any MOQ, so I need to find their child and get MOQ.
Child option may be simple products or Configurable products. But their MOQ was define inside the bundle.
Please help

Comment: you means get bundle child product ???

Comment: yes, bundle child product default quantity

Comment: check this link --- https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-all-children-items-of-bundle-products-magento-2/

Comment: I just try, but I don't get it where the dynamic SKU came from? is it the same as bundle product SKU?

Comment: this function `public function getChildrenItems()` added below the bundle product sku